# How does this OP amp circuit with a transistor work?

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, shunt

I've got a question regarding this schematic. How exactly does it work? I've heard that this could be a current-voltage converter. Is this correct? How do I calculate the voltage on the emmitter if the shunt is e.g. a 3mOhm resistor with a current of 10A?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BJT starts to turn on when Vshunt- falls below Vshunt+. This BJT action is an attempt to make the op-amp input voltages (V+ and V-) the same. This is negative feedback in action.

In other words, the voltage across the 15k resistor (in the emitter) is at 0V when the shunt voltages are the same (i.e. no current flowing thru the shunt) and, as Vshunt- starts to fall relative to Vshunt+, the two op-amp inputs are forced equal by the BJT dumping current thru its emitter resistor. The BJT has no-choice because it is contained within the op-amp's negative feedback loop.

> How do I calculate the voltage on the emmitter if the shunt is e.g. a
>   3mOhm resistor with a current of 10A?

10A thru 3 milli ohms makes Vshunt- 30mV below Vshunt+. Because Vshunt- appears on Vin-, the transistor will drag Vin+ down by 30mV to keep the op-amp in its linear region. This requires a current thru the 270R resistor of 30mV/270ohms = 111.11 uA.

The 111.11 uA then appears as a voltage across the 15kohm resistor. V = IR = 1.6667 volts.

So, with 0A flowing the emitter voltage is zero volts but with 10A flowing the voltage rises to 1.6667V.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very similar circuit from the datasheet of TI's [LMP8646](http://www.ti.com/product/LMP8646/datasheet):

[image]

Note that in the feedback loop, the transistor inverts the feedback, so that even though feedback connects to the non-inverting input, it's still negative feedback.

In order to equalize the voltage of the two inputs, the control loop will need to pull enough current through R<sub>IN</sub> to create a drop across R<sub>IN</sub> equal to the drop across the shunt. This current will be equal to \$I_{\mathrm{sense}}\frac{R_\mathrm{shunt}}{R_\mathrm{IN}}\$, so usually a pretty small value.

In the TI circuit, essentially all of this current will flow through the transistor to R<sub>O</sub>, and the voltage at V<sub>RG</sub> will be $$R_{\mathrm{RG}}I_{\mathrm{sense}}\frac{R_\mathrm{shunt}}{R_\mathrm{IN}}$$

The buffer will just reproduce this same voltage at the output with lower output impedance.

Note that in your circuit there will be a slight difference due to the BJT adding some base current to the output.

Answer (score 1):

One way to learn about how a circuit like this works it to plug it into a circuit simulator like the free for use LT-Spice from Linear Technology.

Here I show how I put in your simple circuit. Note that the opamp in this circuit is a current feedback amplifier as opposed to the more conventional voltage feedback type. In the simulation I did the current through the shunt resistor R5 is varied from 0 to 10 amps.

[image]

The following picture shows the output voltage across the R4 emitter resistor. Note that for this circuit topology the output voltage does not go all the way to zero volts so if you connected this into some A/D converter subsystem you would have to apply an offset calibration and a gain scale to have the A/D readings represent the actual shunt current value.

[image]